# How to access the value of one atribute in pymogo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to pymongo and mongo db and created a cluster with the database and the collection I need. I have added data to the Collection but i'm having trouble retrieving the data as individual values. I need to find the only record where the Gender is female and check the Name belonging to that record, Not been able to find help online. Sorry if it's a noob question

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb+srv://@test-v6kig.mongodb.net/admin')
testdb = client['mytestdb']
testcol = testdb['mytestcol']

myquery = { "Gender" : "Female" }
data = testcol.find(myquery)
if "Need to get value of NAME attribute in the data record" == "Sushmit":
    print("Y")
else:
    print("N")
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

use find_one methods and pass to it the id parameter like this:

```
    single_value= testcol.find_one({'id'})
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_one` always returns a single result which is a JSON document. `find` always returns a cursor (even if there is only a single result or no results). So to get the results from your `find` query you would do:

```py
cursor=pymongo.find(myquery)
for doc in cursor:
    print(doc)
```